# facebook like button: my application replaced by like social plugins

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I copy paste the facebook like button from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator

I insert that, problem is:
The button appears, 
 instead of liking my own page, it likes "social plugins" 2.3 millions !

What may I missed ?

[image]

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1654009128211856";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter your url on the configurer which you can find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button):

[image: Facebook like configurer]

You must have left the default link which is:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Which has 2.3 million likes!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a form on that page that you plug in values, before you click "Get Code" to get cut-in-paste HTML code.

If you left their default URL in "URL to Like" there instead of your URL, this behavior would be explained